# Unable to click and select the value from dynamic drop down

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Unable to click and select the value from dynamic drop down. Please find the below piece of code -

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    //System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\Chrome Driver\\chromedriver.exe");
    //WebDriver Driver = new ChromeDriver();

    WebDriver Driver = new FirefoxDriver();
    Driver.get("http://www.spicejet.com/");

    Driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS)

    Driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='ctl00_mainContent_ddl_originStation1_CTXT']")).click();
 }
```

Also I notice that Eclipse keeps on running after opening the `Spicejet.com` and it does not click on any drop down. To stop the execution I need to click manually on the `Terminate` button else it will not stop and go on for long time (4-6 hrs I believe)

Comment: Why do you run these in 'main' function? Is there any code apart from the above which is using some loop or something which causes the test to keep running!?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use following code to select any value, In this code, I selected Goa (GOI). For more information, it is not a dropdown. It is a web table.

```
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
    driver.manage().window().maximize();
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    driver.get("http://www.spicejet.com/");

    driver.findElement(By.id("ctl00_mainContent_ddl_originStation1_CTXTaction")).click();
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='dropdownGroup1']/div/ul[2]/li[4]/a")).click();
```

Answer (score 0):

When I open that website, it sometimes seems to wait for the user to choose mobile or desktop site.  Is that why it's hanging?

If I click past that (either with Selenium code or manually):

```
 x1path = "//a[@class='desktop-view-button']"
 WebDriverWait(driver,15).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH,x1path)))
 driver.find_element_by_xpath(x1path).click()
```

this code opens the menu:

```
 x1path = '//*[@id="ctl00_mainContent_ddl_originStation1_CTXTaction"]'
 WebDriverWait(driver,15).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH,x1path)))
 driver.find_element_by_xpath(x1path).click()
```

But then you have to choose which dropdown element you want (I don't think your code does that.)

```
 x1path = '//div[@id="dropdownGroup1"]/div/ul/li[6]/a'
 WebDriverWait(driver,15).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH,x1path)))
 driver.find_element_by_xpath(x1path).click()
```

The `ul/li[6]` selects the 6th element in the first column (Belagavi).